# When shall I create UML diagrams when developing software?

Tags: uml, software-design, requirements

I am currently working on a new software and I am not sure how to go on.

I already started coding before having a good plan.

My opinion was to start with below sequence

1. Create User Stories
2. Create BMSC & Hsmc
3. Code the required features
4. Test
5. Refactor & solve bugs

Now I want to know where do I put the UML Diagram, before coding or after coding?

Comment: See also http://www.agilemodeling.com/

Comment: This is simply too broad/opinion based. There are tons of books on how to **best** use a design process. Each book claims to have the **best** answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with starting to code before having a plan. Just be ready to refactor your code whenever neccessary, maybe even throw it away completely. One step I am missing is writing tests. Finally, why do you want to create an UML diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, there can not be a ultimate answer here.

There are various process models and you have to find one that suits your needs and your project.

**Test driven development** for example puts tests in front of writing the actual code.

My point is, if you feel like **UML** gives you confidence - go do it.
But if you feel like a minimal working example gives you more insights - write some code first and come back to uml later.

Answer (score 0):

UML is the "graphical" design of a project. Before you start coding, you should have all UML's done and **checked** so as programming the project later will be faster, easier and with less errors (as the UML will be **CHECKED** to ensure that).

Do not rush making the UML, as it will be the "core" before the actual coding core.

Comment: What or who will check the UML? While there are great tools to check code, the tooling to check UML is pretty poor, as far as I know.

Comment: @FrankPuffer UML should be checked with the potential application users (Subject Matter Experts) to ensure completeness and correctness.

Comment: @Ister: I strongly doubt that the typical subject matter expert can read UML. Even if they can, it will be difficult to use UML as a basis for completeness and correctness checking of nontrivial systems.